# generate a sequence array in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Is there an intrinsic in Fortran that generates an array containing a sequence of numbers from a to b, similar to python's `range()`

```
>>> range(1,5)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range(6,10)
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

?

Comment: How does python's range() work?

Answer (score 34):

No, there isn't.

You can, however, initialize an array with a constructor that does the same thing,

```
program arraycons
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  real :: a(10) = (/(i, i=2,20, 2)/)
  print *, a
end program arraycons
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as in range() above? I don't see the difference (well, apart from the <= and <, and the fact that fortran isn't a dynamic language). Maybe I understood the question wrong (or the answer).

Comment: @Rook: It's an array constructor with an implied do loop, not an intrinsic.

Comment: A-ah, yes. I completely missed that part in the question.

Comment: @janneb thank you.  Would you mind explaining which each argument to the constructor does?  Am I right in thinking that this gives 2, 4, ... , 20?  And is this more efficient than an explicit `DO` loop, or is it equivalent?

Comment: It is similar to a Python list comprehension.

Comment: This is truly list comprehension magic!  I can even call a function in the constructor. OMG I'm gonna use this more often.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

If you need to support floats, here is a Fortran subroutine similar to `linspace` in NumPy and MATLAB.

```
! Generates evenly spaced numbers from `from` to `to` (inclusive).
!
! Inputs:
! -------
!
! from, to : the lower and upper boundaries of the numbers to generate
!
! Outputs:
! -------
!
! array : Array of evenly spaced numbers
!
subroutine linspace(from, to, array)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: from, to
    real(dp), intent(out) :: array(:)
    real(dp) :: range
    integer :: n, i
    n = size(array)
    range = to - from

    if (n == 0) return

    if (n == 1) then
        array(1) = from
        return
    end if


    do i=1, n
        array(i) = from + range * (i - 1) / (n - 1)
    end do
end subroutine
```

Usage:

```
real(dp) :: array(5)
call linspace(from=0._dp, to=1._dp, array=array)
```

Outputs the array

```
[0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.]
```

Here `dp` is

```
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(p = 15, r = 307) ! Double precision
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create a function that reproduces precisely the functionality of range in python:

```fortran
module mod_python_utils
contains
  pure function range(n1,n2,dn_)
     integer,           intent(in) :: n1,n2
     integer, optional, intent(in) :: dn_
     integer, allocatable :: range(:)
     integer ::dn
     dn=1; if(present(dn_))dn=dn_
     if(dn<=0)then
        allocate(range(0))
     else
        allocate(range(1+(n2-n1)/dn))
        range=[(i,i=n1,n2,dn)]
     endif
  end function range
end module mod_python_utils

program testRange
   use mod_python_utils
   implicit none
   integer, allocatable :: v(:)
   v=range(51,70)
   print"(*(i0,x))",v
   v=range(-3,30,2)
   print"(*(i0,x))",v
   print"(*(i0,x))",range(1,100,3)
   print"(*(i0,x))",range(1,100,-3)
end program testRange
```

The output of the above is

```
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
-3 -1 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29
1 4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64 67 70 73 76 79 82 85 88 91 94 97 100
```

Notice that :

1. the last line is empty: Fortran treats graciously zero-length arrays.
2. allocated variables get automatically deallocated once out of scope.